# windows batch: how to escape characters from argument values?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, escaping

trying to pass a long string to the android emulator. So i have to encode my input in a away that `cmd` parses and then in a way `sh` parses as that's what `adb` (the tool i'm using to ultimately get the input text to the android emulator)  uses.

simply it's: CMD -> adb.exe -> sh -> telnet

The main issue is the adb.exe->sh step. I have to escape (add `\` before) several characters. The ones i'm recalling now are `;` and `(` and `)`.

So in the flow above, for the 1st (CMD) step i'd have as input: `abc 123 ();`

But for the 2nd step (adb.exe) i have to pass in `adb.exe ... "abc" 62 "123" 62 "\(\)\;"`

The breaking in the spaces i think i can do with `FIND` (or simply use the default argument separation, as i'm using to simplify the sample of what i have so far bellow), but the replacement map (`;` -> `\;`), is there any easy way to do that in a .bat file?

what i have so far is this:

```
@echo off
rem if there are no arguments, exit
IF [%1]==[] exit /B

:loop_args    
rem TODO: escape ';' and '(' and ')'

rem send this argument...
adb shell input text %1

rem ...plus a space
if [%2]==[] exit /B
adb shell input keyevent 62


rem shift to the next argument and continue
SHIFT
goto loop_args
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for several characters.

```
set "var=%~1"
set "var=%var:;=\;%"
set "var=%var:)=\)%"
set "var=%var:(=\(%"

echo "%var%"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the app handles text in the usual way then quotes around the command line text will work like this:

```
batch.bat "ab de fg" "<123 && 456>" "(10 to one)"
```

with this batch file

```
@echo off
:loop
adb shell input text "%~1"
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto :loop
```

Comment: sorry, my question was confusing... let me remove the part about spaces, that was mostly to the `adb` and slightly offtopic.. i can get all the values just quoting, correct. just like you point. Now, the question is, before i pass them down, how do i add `\` before them?